# Can I recover my recent local changes after initiating a rollback in TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

In VS/TFS 2013, in the History screen, when you right click a changeset and select "Rollback Entire Changeset", TFS immediately clobbers all your recent local changes, and attempts to merge where it has merge conflicts.  Deleting files, undoing work.

I made this mistake just now, and I'm looking for a solution that allows me to undo the rollback operation.

Note that I haven't committed anything yet.  However TFS has already deleted local files and undone work, and saved those changes to disk.

In the Merge screen, I was able to select "Undo Rollback" for any file that had merge conflicts.  But for those files that didn't have merge conflicts, they were automatically resolved, and I don't have the option of undoing the rollback.

Is there a way to cancel the rest of this rollback operation without undoing all my local changes?

Is there a way to revert files that were Auto Resolved by the rollback merging into the local changes?

Is there a place on my hard drive where TFS stores the previous version(s) of files it's about to commit?

*Next time, I'll remember to make a shelveset before attempting a rollback.  This sucks.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy to undo the local uncommitted changes .

I always do rollback and branch operations in a separate workspace to avoid conflict.